# "Tracking" ListView with Multiple choices

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view set to multiple choices, my question is is there a way to track what was "checked" by its name?

```
Intent formed = new Intent(this, formedlist.class);
SparseBooleanArray sp=getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
String str="";
for(int i=0;i<sp.size();i++) {
    str+=names[sp.keyAt(i)]+",";
    formed.putExtra("strings", str);
    if(names[sp.keyAt(i)].toString().equals(<String>))
        startActivity(formed);
}
```

is this how I should be iterating through the string? and is the code for the next class that supposed to show the newly formed list is

```
if(names[sp.keyAt(i)].toString().equals(<String>))


//get the Listview from the previous class (this is in a new class seperate from other methods
    Intent formed = getIntent();
    String [] needed = formed.getStringArrayExtra("strings");

    //ArrayAdapter will makes strings appear in the ListView
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, needed));`
```

the way to see what is inside of the list of checked items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem using this approach. Are you having a problem doing it this way?

You are not creating the intent correctly. To create an Intent for navigating to a separate Activity, use this format

```
Intent formed = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
```

If you are never executing inside the if statement, try logging what values you are comparing, or stepping through with the debugger to see where things go awry.

Comment: yes in the line
    `if(names[sp.keyAt(i)].toString().equals("You"))
           startActivity(formed);` 
does not start the activity, it does nothing.

Comment: If you step through with the debugger is that line executed? Could you post the code you use to create this Intent?

Comment: Ewww, please edit that code into the original question and then you can remove the comment. GC means garbage collector, that is normal, same thing happens in Java

Comment: ok so i just edited the code I'm going to add the other class that im using to show the new listview maybe that is the problem

Comment: Before you do that make sure that startActivity gets executed. Put a log statement immediately before it

Comment: okay so i just tried that with this
    `Log.i(TAG, "stuff:" + i);    `
before startactivity and nothing happens, I dont think it displays it Logcat doesnt show anything, im assuming thats where it would show an output being shown if any

Comment: I managed to get the loop to work and it does try and start the new activity after I hit the if statement, now I'm working on getting the newly formed listview to display.